# Printing bools with boost::format as symbolic values?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-format

How do I print boolean values with `boost::format` as symbolic values?

Can this be done without `boost::io::group`? It seems that flags sent to the stream beforehand get retested:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/format.hpp>

int main()
{
  std::cout
    << std::boolalpha
    << true << " "
    << boost::format("%1% %2%\n")
         % true
         % boost::io::group(std::boolalpha, true)
    ;
}
```

Output

```
true 1 true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear to me that you can.

I looked at the Boost.Format documentation and the code, and didn't see anything.

On the other hand, [the sample code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/format/example/sample_userType.cpp) shows how to write a formatter for a user-defined type. You could write one for "bool"

Comment: Since 1.66.0, `boost::format` provides the `b` conversion-specifier which may serve the purpose: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/format/doc/format.html

Answer (score 3):

You can archive that like this:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/format.hpp>

int main()
{
  std::cout
    << std::boolalpha
    << true << " "
    << boost::format("%1$b %2%\n")
         % true
         % boost::io::group(std::boolalpha, true)
    ;
}
```

Comment: Implemented in the boost v1.66